# SQLite3 Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite

I'm trying to transition our excel spreadsheets (being used as a make shift data store) to a database solution. I'm having trouble knowing if I'm on the right path with my tables, though. I've included the SQL for table creation of what I have so far for reference.

The monthly data will come from multiple sources. We want to keep historical data as well on certain metrics. So I'm going to need to create a parts history type thing tracking Onhand, Onorder, etc from month to month. It just seems like I'm missing the... relational part of the relational database. These are mostly facts that need to be queried and aggregated/analyzed. For example, I need a Customer table at all to relate my POS stuff to. I just need to analyze the POS data that is there.

```
CREATE TABLE "Vendors" (
    "VID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Group" INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "VendorInfo" (
    "Vendor_Group" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Display_Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Active" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Last_Update" TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE "Parts" (
    "Vendor_Group" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Vendor_Part" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "OnHand" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "OnOrder" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "Date_Sales_Enabled" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Dropship_Only" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Obsolete_Date" TEXT,
    "Obsolete" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "Discontinued_Date" TEXT,
    "Discontinued" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "Conversion_Date" TEXT,
    "Converted" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    "Conversion_Type" TEXT,
    "Sample_Level" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Vendor_Group, Vendor_Part) 
);
CREATE TABLE "Consigned_POS" (
    "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Vendor_Group" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "Batch_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Transaction_Type" TEXT,
    "Vendor_Part" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Report_Part" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Quantity_Sold" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Cost" REAL NOT NULL,
    "Resale" REAL NOT NULL,
    "Extended_Cost" REAL NOT NULL,
    "Extended_Resale" REAL NOT NULL,
    "Invoice_ID" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Salesorder_ID" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Customer_ID" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Company_Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Invoice_Date" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of otherwise meaningless primary keys (although other columns in the table may also essentially be unique). I would advise against columns that have other meaning as your primary keys. It's minor, but I usually also use singular (not plural) names for my tables.